# html5 video tag error detection in js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, safari, html5-video

Safari 5 in windows XP does not playing video tag. Is there any way that I can detect this is JS.

Basically my requirement is that  I need to show a loading video. If its not supporting, show an image. SO I put the video tag inside a div and gave a background image to this div. But how can I detect whether image is showing or video is playing in js.

thnx
Vinesh

Comment: have you tried modernizr.js? (http://modernizr.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this test if the browser HTML5 video.

```
var supportsHTML5video = !!document.createElement("video").canPlayType;
```